# Как загрузить файл/zip архив на сервер средствами Golang?

Tags: html, apache, golang, localhost

Как можно легко и просто загрузить файл/zip архив на сервер (сервер apache, php 7+) при помощи Golang? Без всяких самописных хендлеров и прочего шлака.

Файл index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
       <title>Upload file</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если вам нужно использовать Golang -  то зачем вообще упомянут сервер и php?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    filePath := "C:\\file\\archive.zip"

    fmt.Println(filePath)
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("uploadfile", filepath.Base(file.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    io.Copy(part, file)
    writer.Close()

    r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost/test/", body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Do(r)
}
```